# How to find elements in an array in vuejs or Javascript

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm having an array of elements in `vuejs`, I've some data manipulation with them Like I've a select dropdown which shows the company information and each company information has a tag. Tags are of one sub level, I've joined both the tags as one and stored in database, whenever I select the parent company I want these tags to be selected, I mean it should have class `btn-warning` and rest all to be `btn-primary` don't be confused with other select, there options are coming from the filter of first select

So suppose my tag data value is: `Investor-Mutual fund`, it should split up and `Investor` button should be selected and `Mutual Fund` button should have class of `btn-primary` and this should be changeable only with the select list only

Here's my code pen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eWXPaK?editors=1010

This will give you idea what I'm trying to do. Guide me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe this is what you want.

```
if (!this.selectedCompanies.length > 0){
  const str = this.model.data.find(d => d.name === newValue.label)
  const [currentTag, selectedTag] = str.tag.split("-")
  this.currentTag =  currentTag
  this.selectedTag =  this.tags[this.currentTag].find(t => t.display === selectedTag)
}
```

Updated [pen](https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/RVdqOg?editors=1010).

Comment: Error in callback for watcher "company_name": "TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined". But I want exactly as you did in codepen :(

Comment: @NitishKumar I don't get an error in the pen. What is the difference?

Comment: Ok solved. Was getting `model.data.type` and was writing `model.data.tag`

Comment: Can I put @click.prevent? in `v-for="tag in tags[currentTag]"`, as while clicking the buttons it is redirecting

Comment: @NitishKumar Not sure how to answer. There doesn't appear to be any reason a re-direct would happen in the pen.